# How to get strict type of value in typescript?

Tags: typescript

For example, I have a function signature as follow:

```
declare function foo<T>(input: T): T;
```

and I hope it returns the strict type of input object without set the template type manually:

```
const bar = foo({ str: 'foo', bool: true })
```

The expected type of `bar` is: `{ str: 'foo', bool: true }`

rather than `{ str: string; bool: boolean }`.

Comment: I saw this in the blog post recently. Check the const assertions section. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-4-rc/

Answer (score 4):

Starting in TypeScript 3.4, write

```
const bar = foo({ str: 'foo', bool: true } as const)
```

Answer (score 3):

I am a big fan of `as const` and the functionality it allows, the problem with it is that it is the caller and not the function that decides if literal types should be used or not. This may lead to confusion of behalf of  the users of `foo`, people will probably forget to add the `as const` and the will get strange errors in other places when the types are not literal types.

If we fall back on the usually way literal types are inferred in typescript we can get `foo` to force literal types be inferred from it's parameter:

```
declare function foo<
   T extends Record<string, V>, 
   V extends string | boolean | number | symbol | null | undefined | Record<string, V>
>(input: T ): T;

const bar = foo({ str: 'foo', bool: true, o: { bar: "bar", n: 1 } }); 

// const bar: {
//     str: "foo";
//     bool: true;
//     o: {
//         bar: "bar";
//         n: 1;
//     };
// }
```

The solution above works for a nested objects, and should work well in most cases and removes the need of callers to add `as const`. This solution works in 3.4 and previous. It relies on the fact that typescript will preserve literal types if they are assigned to a type parameter that is constrained to a type that can be the base type for literal types.